# itunes seems to sync my wife's iphone with  all of MY apps

Tags: iphone, applications

my wife just got an iphone and she did her first sync and its syncing all of my applications (i have an ipod touch).  Is there anyway to have us sync to a separate list of apps?

if i delete these apps off my wife's iphone, are they going to be removed from itunes (and then my ipod next time i sync ?? )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything removed from an iOS device is not removed form iTunes.
Secondly, iTunes sync's all apps that are specified to sync, no matter whose App it is.
iTunes determines the owner to be the Apple ID, which downloaded the App.

Here is an example o the app sync window:
[image: App sync]

Here you can choose the apps to sync. And remember it will upload apps belonging to either of you, but it won't change ownership of them.

Comment: if you are correct, then why is itunes syncing all of MY apps with my wife's iphone.  we have different apple ids

Comment: @ooo - Like I said, you need to specify which apps to sync. iTunes automatically syncs all available apps disregarding "ownership" of the apps.

Comment: thanks.  so for paid apps, you can use on different devices with different apple ids?

Comment: @ooo - Yes you can use them, you just can't update them on the "wrong" Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have one account on the machine with iTunes. @deiga is correct. It will sync all apps that are selected regardless of who "owns" them.

A way around this that may work is separate logins on the machine. On either Mac or Windows, you just create a separate user account and then login as you and 'your' instance of iTunes. I have not tried this on Windows but it works fine on a mac.